# How can I logout from Facebook when the UI fails to respond?

Tags: facebook

OS: Win 7 x64 Pro
Browser: IE11

There're times when Facebook simply stops responding.

The logout URL on Facebook apparently links to https://www.facebook.com/log.out#; I discovered this doing a "View shortcut" after a context-menu click on the "Log out" menu item.

Yet when I attempt to log out from FB by entering aforesaid URL; FB takes me to a "Sorry, this page isn't available" page.

How can I log out from FB using the address-bar?

Comment: "View shortcut" - which browser are you using? I see a `form` (with 3 hidden fields that _might_ be user/session specific?) that is submitted via POST to `https://www.facebook.com/logout.php`. However, trying to navigate to this URL in the browser (a GET request) simply redirects you to your FB home page.

Answer (score 7):

The reason it doesn't work is that clicking the link either takes you to a URL with data that is sent through GET method (i.e the corresponding session id and other details are in the URL) or AJAX method which sends data using JavaScript -- That's to ensure that a person can't simply lead another into going on that URL so they get logged-out.

**Clear The Cookies**

In browsers with a good UI you usually get an option to clear the cookies for a specific domain. So clearing the cookies will erase logged-in status from your browser.

In Chrome you can do that by clicking the small icon on the left of the URL in web address -> click "Show cookies and site data" -> And clear the cookies for `.facebook.com` domain

Clearing cookies aren't a great deal, though doing this many times would require you to verify yourself or should I say the device, as without those cookies Facebook would forget that you even logged in from that device. So it may once in a while require you to either verify by email or phone - just a small code verification.

**Using Mobile Site**

No offence, but if the desktop site of Facebook is too heavy for IE11 to handle you could alternatively use `mbasic.facebook.com` which takes you to a lightweight version of Facebook for mobile (meant for phones from the Jurassic age ;) ) and log-out from their. I am pretty much sure it IE11 wouldn't crash for that small page. The logout button is at the bottom of the page.

**Say no to "Keep Me Logged In"**

While you log-in uncheck the "Keep Me Logged In" checkbox so that when you close your browser your session would end with it.

All you have to do to log out is close your browser and done! (Though I have seen this thing fail, it most of the times never clears the session and I would still be logged in, might be some conflict with the cookies)

Answer (score 3):

Note that you can also logout remotely from Facebook from another session on a different computer or browser.

Go to `Settings` then `Security` then `Where You're Logged In`.
Identify the segment that corresponds to the session you would like to end and select `End Activity`